# Hibernate Interceptor, modifying current state in onSave results in SQL update

Tags: java, hibernate, interceptor

Suppose that I have two classes **Foo** and **Bar**. **Foo** has a *many-to-one* association to **Bar** mapped like this:

```
<many-to-one name="bar" class="Bar" lazy="false" fetch="join" >
    <column name="BAR_ID" sql-type="INTEGER" />
</many-to-one>
```

I've created a custom interceptor that extends from **EmptyInterceptor** and overrides the **onSave** method like this:

```
public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state,
        String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    boolean modified = false;

    if(entity instanceof Foo) {
        Bar bar = new Bar();

        //do some initialization stuff to bar

        for(int i = 0; i < propertyNames.length; i++) {
             if("bar".equals(propertyNames[i])) {
                 state[i] = bar;
                 modified = true;
                 break;
             } 
        }

        //This code essentially gets the current hibernate session and calls save on
        //the passed object.
        BarDAO barDao = BarDAO.INSTANCE;
        barDAO.save(bar);
    }

    return modified;
}
```

The problem is that although an SQL insert statement is executed for bar, an SQL update statement is executed for the entity object, which is a Foo and was modified before insertion. This results in the following Hibernate exception.

> Last cause: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update
>   [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

If I don't save the bar object, an SQL insert statement is executed as expected.

Any insight on what might have gone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do your updates to the **currentState** array in the **onFlushDirty** method in the interceptor.

Had a similar issue because I was modifying the object in the *onLoad* and *onFlushDirty* methods. The problem was that hibernate was thinking that the previous state of the object was the one resulting from the *onLoad* method and the update statement was trying to use those values to find the row in the db table. Might be the same issue because you're modifying the state in the *onSave* method.